# HTML - multiple reference, same wepage

Tags: html

I'm new to web development and have a question. It'd like to add multiple links to the same website on my page. Rather than to add the href="www.mywebsite.com" multiple times to the code, is there anyway to add it to one location and reference it?

For example, this is what I have. The button and the text both take to the same website.

```
<div class="col-md-3 head-main ">             
        <a href="www.mywebsite.com"><i class="fa  color-blue "></i><a>
        <h3>  <a href="www.mywebsite.com" target="_blank">MY WEBSITE</a></h3> 
</div>
```

Comment: You could save the link in a javascript variable then loop over all `a` that you want to reference the link and set their href to your link variable.

Answer (score 1):

If you are linking to the same website as the page is being delivered over, you can use `/` to refer to the root.

For example: `<a href="/">My website</a>` when on `http://example.com/some/path/page.html` will lead to `http://example.com/`

In addition, there is also the HTML `<base>` tag that sets the base URL for all relative paths in a page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base href="http://example.com" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href=".">Goes to http://example.com</a>
    <a href="/">Also goes to http://example.com</a>
    <a href="#anchor">Goes to http://example.com/#anchor</a>
    <a href="some/path/page.html">Goes to http://example.com/some/path/page.html</a>
    <a href="https://stackoverflow.com">Goes to https://stackoverflow.com</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Note that this will apply to **all** relative links used by the document, including references for scripts and stylesheets, so you must be careful. You may want to look into the [pitfalls of `<base>` before using it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889076/is-it-recommended-to-use-the-base-html-tag).